# Winform User Login

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I have a winform application that runs as the pc logged in userA. I want to add a login button that lets a pc userB login to the application while userA is still logged into the PC. The application will then run as UserB. How can this be done ? All i need here is the technical term or an example of this done.

Comment: what kind of login mechanism do you have now? my guess is that you use integrated security. instead just let people log in using a username/password instead of automatically log them in.
and the term you are probally looking for is impersionation.

Comment: Copy the app onto userB's Pc, or change your app to be client server

Comment: i dont have a login mechanism - I want UserB to login with theor PC username and password into the login form of the application. Please note that UserA is still logged into the PC

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think you are missing the point. UserA is logged into the PC and i want another user to be able to loginto the application while UserA is logged into the PC. The application then needs to run under the account of UserB

Comment: Am I? Presumably you aren't talking about UserB throwing UserA out of their chair so they can use UserA's pc?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes - indeed i am - this is for a machine PC that anyone uses - UserA is actuall a generic domain account - The technician needs to goto that pc, login to the application, make some changes and go away again and let userA sit back in the chair.

Comment: Not sure why this question has so many downvotes / close votes, as it seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @Jules. Depends on what the app does as userA.

Comment: @tonyhopkinson what do you mean.? Are you referencing security implications here? If so then that is not the question i asked. I dont know why ppl dont like this stack question.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it seems quite clear to me that the app is intended to normally run as a userA, and the questioner wants to allow another user to provide their username and password to it in order to allow it to gain access to resources that userA is not usually allowed to access.  I don't understand what's so problematic about this.

Comment: This question should not be put on Hold.

Comment: Wasn't me who voted to put on hold, in fact I'd be happy to reopen, if  the OP gave a basic idea what the app did. If it's all internal to the app I don't have an issue. If it isn't there are many potential ones.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson "If it's all internal to the app I don't have an issue" Surely here on SO we should answer the question from a technical perspective. I will take care of the security aspects in the application.

Comment: @user1438082 We try to do more than that here. It's called the XY problem, you asked how to do Y, we believe X is relevant as it might not be the best idea in the world to do Y anyway. It should be noted that impersonate evades security restrictions it does not resolve security requirements...

Comment: We don't believe x is relevant on this question.we put it on hold ....

Comment: You, didn't put it on hold, five SO users who do believe X is relevant did. They closed it for being too broad, giving them some idea of what X is would narrow it down considerably. I know I'd be extremely reluctant to go down the route you've chosen in almost any circumstance.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson thanks Tony. This was certainly a very interesting question and i think we all gained some new knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article contains example C# source code and a description of how to achieve this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C

Briefly summarizing, you need to use the native function `LogonUser` in the `advapi32.dll` library via P/Invoke.  This stores a token handle in a provided `IntPtr` variable, which can then be used via the `DuplicateToken` native function and the `SetThreadToken` function (also in `advapi32.dll`) to make the current thread impersonate the requested user.  The `RevertToSelf` function can be used to return to the original user.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. What intrigues me is that if my question was related to an ASP.net web application under the same scenario, then the solution would be different. Am i correct ?

Comment: I haven't done much work in ASP.net, but I believe it provides its own solution for this.  That said, I suspect you could *also* do it this way in ASP.net, it just wouldn't be a particularly sensible thing to do.

Comment: In fact, if you look at this KB article -  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158 - you will see it suggests pretty-much exactly the same way of doing it in the section "impersonating a specific user in code", so clearly you could do it this way in ASP.net too.